# ACCESS: copy result of query into table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

i want to copy the result of my queries into a table.

i tried this:

```
Function queryintotable()

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient    
rs.Open "target_table", CurrentProject.Connection
rs.Sort = "Retail_ID ASC"

Do Until rs.EOF = True
    DoCmd.CopyObject , "myquery", acQuery, "target_table"    
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox ("Finish! " & Time)

End Function
```

**but i think i forgot something. could u help me please thanks!**

Comment: Why are you using ado when ms access works best with dao? Why are you not following the directions in your previous question?

Comment: Why work hard for what you get for free?

Answer (score 9):

One line of code:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "Select myquery.* Into target_table From myquery"
```

Will create a table named `target_table` containing the result set of `myquery`.

```
CurrentDB.Execute "Insert Into target_table Select myquery.* From myquery"
```

Will insert the result set of `myquery` to an already existing table named `target_table`, with the same structure.